# How can I capture the accelerometer data on iPhone when the app is in background?

Tags: ios, background, accelerometer

In an iOS app, by enabling the flags for VOIP, Audio playback, Location, Bluetooth LE accessories, News stand etc, we can run the app in background. But I've a requirement to create a library/framework that will make the app run in background as well as capture the accelerometer updates and log them to a file.
For that purpose, I enabled "Audio Playback" in the background, and playing a silent file in continuous loop so that app will continue to run in background. At the same time, I'm able to capture the accelerometer data as well. I'm using Core Motion framework for the same and its working perfect.
I would like to add one more point, my app has location tracking enabled to deal with beacons integration.
I want to know if its valid to follow such procedure and will Apple approve it during the review process? Has any one faced this kind of challenge ever?

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed, the only way to access accelerometer data in background is with an active background mode. But...

- Apple will NEVER accept your app if it declares a background mode without any feature actually using it (not just technically like your silent sound, but an actual feature that your user is aware of)
- If you decide to implement a feature that actually use a background mode (like location or audio playback for example), don't forget that you will also drain your user's battery.

---

Conclusion:

- Explain to your client that Apple's restrictions prevent you to do that and have the requirements updated
  or
- Find another feature that will need to use one of the background modes

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I forgot to add that, my app has "location" feature running in the background to track the user's location. So, with Audio play in background, will my solution be acceptable by Apple now?

Comment: If your location feature use continuous location updates (requireLocationUpdatesWhenInUse + Background location = blue status bar when in background), you don't even need the background audio mode.

Comment: I think the key must be "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" + Background location. Am I correct? Because the key "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" in info.plist file is used only when the app is running foreground mode.

Comment: No that's the point. If you use WhenInUse but declare that you need Background location, the system will display a blue status bar and will keep feed location updates to your app. If you use "Always" it won't show the bar, and your app will be woke up only when an update is available.